# Initiate app's video call using Google Assistance

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I want to initiate a video call on my app using google assistance like below

> OK Google, call **ABC** using **MyApp**

where **ABC** is a contact inside my app (not in device) and **MyApp** is the name of my app.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning, Vinil! Invocation directly after "OK Google" or "Hey Google" is reserved for Google employees building Google-branded actions, so I doubt you'll be able to build this functionality.

You can, however, build an app that responds to something like, "Hey Google, talk to Super Awesome Phone App," where Super Awesome Phone App is the name of your app. Thereafter, you'll be able to handle a user's request to "call ABC."

If you want to build a telephony application for Google Assistant, you can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs) and [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/) codelab sequence.

Comment: Then how Whats App is invoking by saying "Ok Google, Send hi to ABC Using Whats App?"

That is possible in offline mode too